# Proving $2\cos(k\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} c(k,r) (2\cos \theta)^{k-2r}$ for $c(k,r)$ as defined

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, summation, recurrence-relations

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. Define for $n\ge 1, 0\leq r\leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$, the integers $c(n,r)$ so that $c(1,0) = 1, c(2,0) = 1, c(2,1) = -2$ and for $n\ge 3$,
> $$\begin{cases}
> c(n,0)\phantom{/2} = 1,\\
> c(n,r)\phantom{/2} = c(n-1, r) - c(n-2, r-1), &1\leq r\leq (n-1)/2,\\
> c(n,n/2) = (-1)^{n/2} 2, &\text{ if $n$ is even}\end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $2\cos(k\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} c(k,r) (2\cos \theta)^{k-2r}$ for any real number $\theta$.

I was thinking of doing a proof by induction, but it seems very complicated to do.

If $k=1, 2$, then
$$2\cos \theta = 2\cos\theta \quad\text{and}\quad 2\cos (2\theta) = (2\cos\theta)^2 + (-2)(2\cos \theta)^{2-2}$$
so the claim holds. So assume the claim holds for all $1\leq n < m$ and $m\ge 3$.

Suppose $m$ is odd. We want to show that
$$2\cos m\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{(m-1)/2} c(m,r) (2\cos \theta)^{m-2r}$$ We know by induction that
$$2\cos(m-1)\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{(m-1)/2} c(m-1, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m-1-2r}$$ and
$$2\cos(m-2)\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{(m-3)/2} c(m-2, r)(2\cos\theta)^{m-2-2r}$$
But then if I use the cosine addition formula on
$$2\cos m\theta = 2\cos ((m-1)\theta + (m-1)\theta - (m-2)\theta)$$ then I get an expression involving sines for which I don't have an explicit formula. Also, if I were to simplify the resulting expression, it would be very complicated.

> Edit: Here's my attempt for even m, based on the first answer for odd m. There's likely a shorter approach though (see Mindlack's comment).

If m is even, then $2\cos ((m-1)\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{(m-2)/2} c(m-1, r) (2\cos \theta)^{m-1-2r}$ and $2\cos ((m-2)\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{(m-2)/2} c(m-2, r) (2\cos\theta)^{m-2-2r}$. We have

$\begin{align}
2\cos m\theta &= 2\cos \theta \cdot 2\cos ((m-1)\theta) - 2\cos((m-2)\theta)\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{(m-2)/2} c(m-1, r) (2\cos \theta)^{m-2r} - \sum_{r=0}^{(m-2)/2}c(m-2, r)(2\cos \theta)^{(m-2) - 2r}\\
&= c(m-1, 0)(2\cos \theta)^m +\sum_{r=0}^{(m-4)/2} c(m-1, r + 1)(2\cos \theta)^{m-2 - 2r} -\sum_{r=0}^{(m-2)/2}c(m-2, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m-2-2r}\\
&= (2\cos \theta)^m - c(m-2, \frac{m-2}2) + \sum_{r=0}^{(m-4)/2}c(m, r+1)(2\cos \theta)^{m-2-2r}\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^{(m-2)/2}c(m, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m-2r} + c(m, m/2) +(2\cos \theta)^m\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{m/2} c(m,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m-2r}\end{align}$

Comment: I believe, $2\cos\theta = e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$ could help.

Comment: Also, cases $k=2n$ and $k=2n+1$ can be considered separately.

Comment: Hint: consider the polynomial $T_n(x)=\sum_{k\leq n/2}{c(n,k)x^{n-2k}}$. Show that $T_{n+2}(x)+T_n(x)=xT_{n+1}(x)$. Show that $(T_n(2\cos{u}))_n$ and $(2\cos{nu})_n$ have the same recurrence relation and the same initial values.

Comment: @Mindlack how did you know that to solve the problem, it was enough to show $T_{n+2}(x) + T_n(x) = xT_{n+1}(x)$? To clarify, I'm not asking how you can show that recurrence, but rather how you came up with it in the first place. Did you just try small values of n? Is there a better method than just listing out values of $T_n(x)$ and trying to find a pattern?

Comment: Expressing $2\cos{k\theta}$ as a polynomial in $2\cos{\theta}$ is a very classical exercise and yields polynomials called the Chebyshev polynomials – which have quite some interesting properties. The recurrence I gave you was the Chebyshev polynomial recurrence, which looked tractable from your problem data. But you could have found it on your own, regarding the RHS as a certain polynomial in $2\cos{\theta}$ and translating the conditions on the $c$-values. Then you would just have to notice that the same recurrence relation held for the LHS.

Comment: @Mindlack which chebyshev polynomial recurrence are you taking about? The one on wikipedia for chebyshev polynomials of the first kind is $T_{n+2}(x) + T_n(x) = 2xT_{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: Let $T_n$ be the Wikipedia Chebyshev polynomial and $M_n$ be the ones I used. Then $M_n(2x)=2T_n(x)$ – so they’re not far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Remarks*: The proof for even $m$ is similar. So I omit it.

**The proof for odd** $m$:

By the inductive hypothesis, we have
$$2\cos (m - 1)\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 1)/2} c(m - 1,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 1 - 2r}$$
and
$$2\cos (m - 2)\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} c(m - 2,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}.$$

Using the identity $\cos m \theta + \cos (m - 2)\theta = 2\cos \theta \cos (m-1)\theta$, we have
\begin{align*}
 2\cos m x &= 2\cos\theta \cdot 2 \cos (m - 1)\theta - 2\cos (m - 2)\theta\\
 &= \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 1)/2} c(m - 1,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2r} - \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} c(m - 2,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}\\
 &= c(m - 1, 0)(2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=1}^{(m - 1)/2} c(m - 1,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2r} \\
 &\qquad - \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} c(m - 2,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}\\
 &= (2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 1)/2 - 1} c(m - 1, 1 + r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r} \\
 &\qquad - \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} c(m - 2,r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}\\
 &= (2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} [c(m - 1, 1 + r) - c(m - 2, r)](2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}\\
 &= (2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 3)/2} c(m, 1 + r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2 - 2r}\\
 &= (2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=1}^{(m - 3)/2 + 1} c(m, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2r}\\
 &= (2\cos \theta)^m - c(m, 0)(2\cos \theta)^m + \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 1)/2} c(m, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2r}\\
 &= \sum_{r=0}^{(m - 1)/2} c(m, r)(2\cos \theta)^{m - 2r}
\end{align*}
where we have used $c(m - 1, 0) = c(m, 0) = 1$.

The desired result follows.